# UITableView Rows selection with UIPicker Option

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a `tableview` with 5 rows, when I select a row it opens a `UIPickerView` in the next page to select options,the same things happen with 5 rows.Now I want ,The Pickervalue, It should be reflected on particular Row(right side) whichever I selected

and I have a button on the same page to perform on the selected rows values(UIPicker values).How to give options in Button.to select the Rows values which is been taken from `UIPicker`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(indexPath.row==0){

        Picker1 *logInController = [[Picker1 alloc] init];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:logInController animated:YES];
    }

    if(indexPath.row==1){

        Picker2 *logInController = [[Picker2 alloc] init];

        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:logInController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

like above I have opened the `UIPIcker` and select the options.

IN PICKER1.m

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    // update label text to show selected option

    NSString* string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"you are selected %@",[list objectAtIndex:row]];

    label.text=string;

}



- (void)viewDidLoad

{      
    [super viewDidLoad];

    list =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [list addObject:@"GPS"];
    [list addObject:@"NONE"];


}
```

Comment: -1 ; is there a question here?  if so, your question should be more easy for people to find.

Comment: I want when I select row,it will open UIPickerView,and PickerView selected value.how to reflect selected PickerView value in the row.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to modify datasource of tableView. You can take array of dictionaries(with keys leftTitle & rightTitle).
2. You need to implement protocol in Picker1 & Picker2 with delegate method valueSelected:
3. Implement delegate in your controller with tableView.
4. You need to save globally index of selected row. Set delegate to self while pushing pickers.
5. When you tap on button in picker controller call valueSelected: delegate & pass value selected in picker.
6. In Your controller with tableView where you have implemented protocol methods, get value and save in datasource(as value for key "rightTitle" in dictionary with selected index).
7. Reload table.

Comment: thanks.is there any sample code available,so that it would be more helpful    for me.

Comment: Right now I don't have any sample code. But I had implemented it same way. Tell me if you don't understand any step.

Comment: can u tell me how to store in dictionaries(with keys leftTitle & rightTitle).

Comment: Take NSMutableDictionary and add values in it for keys you want. 
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"value1", @"leftTitle", @"value2", @"rightTitle", nil];

Then add this dictionary in array(data for table view) for each row you have.(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)